# What is the proper way to use flink-connector-gcp-pubsub

Tags: deserialization, apache-flink, publish-subscribe

I don't know what should be filled in the DeserializationSchema parameter.

```java
PubSubSource<RecordArrayInfo> source = PubSubSource.newBuilder()
    .withDeserializationSchema(*WhatSchema(?)*)
    .withProjectName(projectId)
    .withSubscriptionName(subscriptionName)
    .withCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(getAutheficateFile()))
    .build();
```

I found there is an interface named `PubSubDeserializationSchema`. Maybe I can write a class implements that interface can be filled in the above blank?

> The deserialization schema describes how to turn the PubsubMessages
> into data types (Java/Scala objects) that are processed by Flink. Type
> parameters:  – The type created by the deserialization schema.
>
> ```
> public interface PubSubDeserializationSchema<T> extends Serializable,
> ResultTypeQueryable<T> {}
> ```

[image: Screenshot]

But I don't know what should be filled in the parameter `T`, `Type` parameters:

> `<T>` – The type created by the deserialization schema.'

Is this `T` schema pub/sub message schema or user data schema?

I think maybe the front one, because user data schema can't be read directly, it was encrypted. So if it was the pub/sub message schema, maybe it is a common one I needn't write by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Deserialization is always an operation that takes "on wire" data (in your case a PubSub Message) and turns it into a desired format/representation. We can see that in [JavaDocs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/gcp/pubsub/common/PubSubDeserializationSchema.html). There is a method that you need to override:

```java
T deserialize(com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage message) throws Exception
```

as you can see, it returns type parameter `T`, which is the type that you want to use in your application. It accepts PubsubMessage and it is up to you to implement a logic that transforms the PubsubMessage to your desired type.

For example: if you store JSON objects in your PubSub then you can read bytes as UTF-8 string and deserialize it to the desired object using Jackson. You need to implement that in the class that implements the `PubSubDeserializationSchema`.

In your case, you already have a hint of what the `T` should be. You have `PubSubSource<RecordArrayInfo>` where `RecordArrayInfo` is a type of the elements of the resulting stream. In that case, you need to implement a class like this:

```java
class RecordArrayInfoDeserializer implements PubSubDeserializationSchema<RecordArrayInfo>
```

and override all required methods.

When you implement this then you can construct your source like this:

```java
        PubSubSource<RecordArrayInfo> source = PubSubSource.newBuilder()
                .withDeserializationSchema(new RecordArrayInfoDeserializer())
                .withProjectName(projectId)
                .withSubscriptionName(subscriptionName)
                .withCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(getAutheficateFile()))
                .build();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. And I got some enlightenment from your answer.
what puzzled me this morning is how to analysis pubsub message, I thought maybe I need an precise schema of the pubsub message.
but actually, the message has already been formed as a class of PubsubMessage and no need me to offer a schema and transfer to that form, right?
so I can get the content of the message directly, then transfer these messages to whatever I want ,right?
so am I used it correctly as follows?

Comment: Yes, the source already provides you with Pubsub Message, no need for parsing that yourself. The only thing you need to do is to produce the object that you want based on the content of the PubsubMessage. Exactly as in the code that you shared below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76261412/12396982).

Answer (score 0):

[use of PubsubMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMcaK.jpg)

```
public class RecordArrayInfoDeserializer  implements PubSubDeserializationSchema<RecordArrayInfo> {

@Override
public boolean isEndOfStream(RecordArrayInfo nextElement) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public RecordArrayInfo deserialize(PubsubMessage message) throws Exception {
    // a lot of parameters can be got here directly
    message.getData().toStringUtf8();
    message.getAttributesMap();
    message.getMessageId();
    /**
     * some method to generate an object of class RecordArrayInfo,
     * then return this object
     */
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).